# Make ng test ChromeHeadless to display the description in "describe" and "it" of a spec.ts file

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

How to make `ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless` to display the description in `describe()` and `it()` of a spec.ts file?

e.g.:

```
ng test --include=src/app/interval/interval.spec.ts
```

display this in the Chrome browser:

```
finished in 0.039s
1 spec, 0 failures, randomized with seed 41004
interval
should emit every millisecond
```

where:

```
interval
should emit every millisecond
```

come from the description in "describe()" and "it()" in my interval.spec.ts:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { testScheduler } from '../test_scheduler';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('interval', () => {
    it('should emit every millisecond', () => {
        testScheduler.run((helpers) => {
            const { expectObservable } = helpers;
            const numbers$ = interval(1).pipe(take(2));
            expectObservable(numbers$).toBe('-0(1|)', {'0': 0, '1': 1});
        });
    });
});
```

However, my desired output is:

```
interval
should emit every millisecond
```

Do not appear when running:

```
ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --no-watch --progress --include=src/app/interval/interval.spec.ts
```

Actual output:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
29 12 2023 07:33:28.830:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
29 12 2023 07:33:28.833:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
29 12 2023 07:33:28.842:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
29 12 2023 07:33:29.577:INFO [Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket LwJzp9zIOKI1y83KAAAB with id 33092643
Chrome Headless 117.0.5938.132 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.002 secs / 0.01 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

versions:
"@angular/cli": "^17.0.8",
"jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

You need the [karma-jasmine-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) plugin.

First install it using `npm`

```
npm install karma-jasmine-html-reporter --save-dev
```

Then define it inside `karma.conf.js`

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: Angular 16 has deprecated Karma and introduced Jest in experimental mode.